# Pandas groupby: combine distinct values into another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to group by a subset of columns and count the number of distinct combinations of their values. However, there are other columns that may or may not have distinct values, and I want to somehow retain this information in my output. Here is an example:

```
gb1          gb2         text1   text2
bebop        skeletor    blue    fisher
bebop        skeletor    blue    wright
rocksteady   beast_man   orange  haldane
rocksteady   beast_man   orange  haldane
tokka        kobra_khan  green   lande
tokka        kobra_khan  red     arnold
```

I **only** want to group by `gb1` and `gb2`.

Here is what I need:

```
gb1          gb2         count   text1        text2
bebop        skeletor    2       blue         fisher, wright
rocksteady   beast_man   2       orange       haldane
tokka        kobra_khan  2       green, red   lande, arnold
```

I've got everything working except for handling the `text1` and `text2` columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check with

```
s=df.assign(count=1).groupby(['gb1','gb2']).agg({'count':'sum','text1':lambda x : ','.join(set(x)),'text2':lambda x : ','.join(set(x))}).reset_index()
s
          gb1         gb2  count      text1          text2
0       bebop    skeletor      2       blue  wright,fisher
1  rocksteady   beast_man      2     orange        haldane
2       tokka  kobra_khan      2  green,red   lande,arnold
```

Comment: thanks a bunch, but I forgot to include that I need to do this join for two separate columns. I updated my explanation: sorry about that. How can I get this to work for two separate joined columns?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html#pandas.DataFrame.transform):

If `df` is your original dataframe:

```
def combine(xx):
    dd = xx.transform(lambda x : ','.join(set(x)))
    dd['count'] = len(xx)
    return dd

ddf = df.groupby(['gb1', 'gb2']).apply(combine)
```

With your sample dataframe, `ddf` is:

```
                           text1          text2  count
gb1        gb2                                        
bebop      skeletor         blue  fisher,wright      2
rocksteady beast_man      orange        haldane      2
tokka      kobra_khan  red,green   lande,arnold      2
```